# How to write formatted integers to file in i18n-friendly way in Java?

Tags: java, file, internationalization, streamwriter, filewriter

I'm currently using

```
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("open_sites_20,txt"), "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(String.format("%4d%4d%n", i, j));
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.print("error: " + e.toString() + "\n");
        };
```

where i, j are integers.

FindBugs reports that the above has the following bad practice

```
Reliance on default encoding
Found a call to a method which will perform a byte to String (or String to byte) conversion, and will assume that the default platform encoding is suitable. This will cause the application behaviour to vary between platforms. Use an alternative API and specify a charset name or Charset object explicitly.
```

Any suggestion how this can be improved?

Platform: IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1 + FindBugs-IDEA 0.9.992.

Comment: You are already specifying encoding when creating the `OutputStreamWriter`. Where exactly does FindBigs report the problem?

Comment: Right on the line of `BufferedWriter writer ...`.

Comment: If FindBugs is actually reporting it on the lines you indicate, it seems that FindBugs is incorrect. Either it is getting thrown off by some internal implementation detail of one of the streams somehow, or it's just being very liberal with its warnings, or you've found a bug in FindBugs.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, FindBugs seems to be wrong. Please keep in mind that its rules are not carved into stone, so it is necessary to apply your own judgment.

As for improving things. There are few way you can improve this code. First, let's deal with character encoding. Since Java 1.4, `OutputStreamWriter` [contains constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter-java.io.OutputStream-java.nio.charset.Charset-) with the following signature:

```
OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream stream, Charset charEncoding)
```

It's better to use this, instead of passing the encoding name as string. Why? Starting with Java 7, you can use [StandardCharsets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) enum to create a `Charset` class instance. Therefor you can write:

```
new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("open_sites_20,txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

I don't think FindBugs would argue about that.

Another issue I see here, is the way you close writer. In some circumstances, this method will not be called. The best way to deal with it (if you are using Java 7 and above) is to use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and let Java close streams/writers:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
         new FileOutputStream("open_sites_20,txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));) {
    writer.write(String.format("%4d%4d%n", i, j));
    // It always make sense to flush the stream before closing
    writer.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.print("error: " + e.toString() + "\n");
};
```

Now, all you do is write single value to file. If I were you, I would try to avoid all the overhead of creating streams, wrapping it with writers and so on. It's complicated. Fortunately, Java 7 has one fantastic class to help you write things to text files: [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).
The class has two methods that come in handy when you need to write something to a text file:

```
write(Path path, byte[] bytes, OpenOption... options)
write(Path path, Iterable<? extends CharSequence> lines, Charset cs, OpenOption... options)
```

The first one could also be used to write binary files. Second could be used to write a collection of strings (array, list, set, ...). Your program could be rewritten as:

```
try {
    Path outputPath = Paths.get("open_sites_20,txt");
    String nmbrStr = String.format("%4d%4d%n", i, j);
    byte[] outputBytes = nmbrStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    Files.write(outputPath, outputBytes, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    LOGGER.severe(ioe);
}
```

That's it!
Simple and elegant. What I used here:

- [Paths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html)
- [String.getBytes(Charset charEncoding)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-) - I can't guarantee that FindBugs won't complain about this one
- [StandardOpenOption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html)
- [Java Logging API](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Logging/article.html) - instead writing exceptions to System.out